# Formula for the Dirichlet inverse cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to write a function in Python that provides random numbers from a Dirichlet distribution. For instances, this is already done with numpy.random.dirichlet. However, I need to make a new function to make use of low discrepancy sequences such as the Sobol distribution. I have no problems to get numbers from a Sobol distribution

So, my code should take as an input a series of uniformly distributed random numbers from Sobol’s and transform the series using an inverse cumulative density function (cdf) to give me as an output a series of random numbers from a Dirichlet distribution. Unfortunately, in Python, scipy.stats.dirichlet does not contain the method ‘ppf’ (percent point function) that would do this job for me.

I have been searching for the mathematical expression of the inverse cdf of a Dirichlet distribution, but I have not found any. This is what I need to implement it in my code. Any help to find it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I assume that by "cumulative density function" you mean the cumulative distribution function. What do you mean by an inverse cumulative distribution function in the context of a multivariate distribution? Do you want to take $k$ Sobol numbers at a time and transform them to a $k+1$-dimensional vector with Dirichlet distribution? Or do you have a $2$-dimensional Dirichlet distribution that can be characterized by a $1$-dimensional cumulative distribution function?